# Upgrade JSF application deployed on weblogic without downtime

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I have simple Java Server Faces application deployed on Weblogic server. How I can upgrade the package with zero downtime?

For example can I create cluster of nodes and switch the active nodes or I can do this using only one node?

Answer (score 0):

You can [specify a version](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/programming/versioning.html#wp1021388) in `MANIFEST.MF` and weblogic will transparently switch over to the new version on deployment, waiting for old sessions to close and routing new sessions to the new version.

Bear in mind that certain versions of WLS can't parse the version to a decimal, it will treat it as a string, so unless you want `v1.9.6` to replace `v1.10.0`, just make it a decimal number.

Comment: So I need to only replace the package?

Comment: Well, you'll need an outage the first time, because the package that you have at the moment doesn't have a version so Weblogic won't know which one to replace.

But after that, you just deploy the newer version and it will replace it vaguely-transparently.